# Adding Unique Objects to Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, object

I have an object called Filter that stores information about Car Types. This information is retrieved via AJAX and on first ajax call objects 0-10 are created and pushed to an array. On the second ajax call, more car types are returned and are added to the array.

**My question is:** I only want to add objects to the array with a unique label. So for the next AJAX call, I only want to add the object with label "Hybrid" to the array. Here's what I have, for some reason the indexOf method doesn't seem to be working and is adding all new car types with same label to the array.

**Code:**

```
var filter_object = Object.create(Filter);
filter_object.init(label, $(this).val());


if (types.indexOf(filter_object.label) == -1)
   types.push(filter_object);


  var Filter = {
     init: function (label, value) {
        this.label = label;
        this.value = value;
     }
  };
```

**Sample Objects:**

```
0:   {label: "All Car Types", value: "on"}
1:   {label: "Small Cars", value: "CCAR,ECAR,CDAR,EDAR"}
2:   {label: "Medium Cars", value: "ICAR,SCAR,IDAR"}
3:   {label: "Large Cars", value: "FCAR,PCAR,FDAR"}
4:   {label: "SUVs & Crossovers", value: "IFAR,SFAR,CFAR,RFAR,FFAR,PFAR"}
5:   {label: "Vans", value: "MVAR,RVAR,FVAR"}
6:   {label: "Luxury", value: "LCAR,LDAR"}
7:   {label: "Convertibles", value: "STAR"}
8:   {label: "Sports", value: "SSAR"}
9:   {label: "Commercial", value: "SKAR"}
10:  {label: "Specialty", value: "XXAR"}


// Next AJAX Call
11: {label: "All Car Types", value: "on"}
12: {label: "Small Cars", value: "ECAR,MCAR,CCAR,CDAR,EDAR"}
13: {label: "Hybrids", value: "ICAH,FCAH"}
```

Comment: You can't test objects with other objects. They are different instances and therefore not equal, ie `{} != {}`

Comment: And even if you could, passing a label to `indexOf()` won't work since the array doesn't contain strings but objects. Also, why not use an Object instead of an Array in the first place, where label is the key and value is the value? That way it doesn't matter if the key already exists; it'll simply get overwritten.

Comment: Is it possible to look at piece of object? I only want to look at the label of the object vs. the label of the object in the Types array.

Comment: @Michael Yes, but not with `indexOf()`. Check the answer you got.

Comment: Can you provide more of the code? a good bit of useful information is missing.

Comment: Do you call `init` more than once per object?  If not, why not initialize the fitler object more directly?  `var filter_object = {label, value: $(this).val()}`?

Answer (score 1):

I had an earlier attempt which missed the requirement that values had to be combined.  I'm still not sure about your data structures, but if these can be simple objects collected in arrays, then this might do:

```js
const combineValues = (v1, v2) => {
  const a1 = v1.split(','), a2 = v2.split(',');
  return a1.concat(a2.filter(v => !(a1.includes(v)))).join(',')
}
// combineValues('a,b,c,d', 'a,b,c,e,f') //=> "a,b,c,d,e,f"

const combineTypes = (types, newTypes) => {
  return types.map(type => {
    const matchType = newTypes.find(t => t.label === type.label) || type
    return {label: type.label, value: combineValues(type.value, matchType.value)}
  }).concat(newTypes.filter(type => types.every(t => t.label !== type.label)))
}


const types = [{"label": "All Car Types", "value": "on"}, {"label": "Small Cars", "value": "CCAR,ECAR,CDAR,EDAR"}, {"label": "Medium Cars", "value": "ICAR,SCAR,IDAR"}, {"label": "Large Cars", "value": "FCAR,PCAR,FDAR"}, {"label": "SUVs & Crossovers", "value": "IFAR,SFAR,CFAR,RFAR,FFAR,PFAR"}, {"label": "Vans", "value": "MVAR,RVAR,FVAR"}, {"label": "Luxury", "value": "LCAR,LDAR"}, {"label": "Convertibles", "value": "STAR"}, {"label": "Sports", "value": "SSAR"}, {"label": "Commercial", "value": "SKAR"}, {"label": "Specialty", "value": "XXAR"}]
const newTypes = [{"label": "All Car Types", "value": "on"}, {"label": "Small Cars", "value": "ECAR,MCAR,CCAR,CDAR,EDAR"}, {"label": "Hybrids", "value": "ICAH,FCAH"}]


const updated = combineTypes(types, newTypes)
console.log(updated)
```

Note that this combines the values inside "Small Cars" and adds "Hybrids".  It does not mutate any of your data but creates a new array with new objects.

There is a bit of silly inefficiency included for code simplicity.  When no matching new type is found, we call `combineValues` on a type and itself, clearly useless.  While it would not be hard to fix this, the code would be somewhat uglier.  Given the likely number of elements, I can't imagine that this would be problematic.

Comment: Hi Scott - I'm having a bit of trouble implementing your solution with my actual code. Here's what I have so far: http://prntscr.com/jazly7 ...I added a comment with a description of what this is doing and what I'm trying to achieve. Let me know if you'd be able to help. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: This code solves the issue of adding only unique labels http://prntscr.com/jazp8i, but doesn't solve the issue of adding all unique values (ex. MCAR)

Comment: Without seeing your HTML I don't really have a sense of this.  If you got it to work, great!  Next time you want to share code here, if you can, put it in the question, ideally in a snippet.  If there's too much, use something like CodePen, JSFiddle, or JSBin.  It makes collaborating much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.some` of es6 like

```
if (!types.some(e=> e.label === filter_object.label))
 types.push(filter_object);
```

Note: The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: You mean the opposite of that? :)

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad to know that. Consider accepting the answer -:)

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Could I use some() to check whether or not the same label has a different or new/value? For example: in the 2nd AJAX call for  Small Cars...there is a new value `MCAR`. Wondering if I can use some() to look at previous Small Cars values ("CCAR,ECAR,CDAR,EDAR") and then insert MCAR into here.

Comment: like `e=> e.label === filter_object.label && e.values === filter_object.values`

Comment: Why `!x.some(... a === b)` rather than `x.every(... a !== b)`?  Any particular reason?  Obviously they're equivalent, but to me the latter sounds closer to the problem description.

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. If the 1st AJAX call for "Small Cars" is `CCAR,ECAR,CDAR,EDAR`, and for the 2nd AJAX the value is `ECAR,MCAR,CCAR,CDAR,EDAR`....I need to update the object's value with adding MCAR since the value already contains ECAR, CCAR, CDAR, and EDAR. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array of all of your existing labels as a lookup, then call `.reduce` on your incoming array like this:

```
const existingLabels = existing.map(item => item.label);

const updated = newItems.reduce((all, item) => {
  if (!existingLabels.includes(item.label))
      all.push(item);

  return all;
}, existing);
```